How can I write a screen check or text check in macrodroid
Screen check text if have in the app screen Hungary text then write Done And swipe one right   else not see Hungary text then go left
X y position And repeat Until the user stops the macro by pressing a button
I try it to do it but don't going for me
Just once but can't repeat the action
